# got a circular reference while serializing using Controller.Json() method

Tags: entity-framework-4, reference, poco

I have a model edmx model and am using POCO like this:

```
public class ContactPerson
    {
        public virtual Guid ContactPersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual string FullName { get; set; }     
        public virtual Guid PositionId { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Birthday { get; set; }       
        public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
          }

public class Position
    {
        public virtual Guid PositionId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContactPerson> ContactPersons { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to serialize `from a in _context.Positions select a` using Json() method, it detects a circular reference. I belive this happens because Position have a reference to ContactPersons collection and ContactPerson at same time have a reference to Position.

The question is obvious, what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) at ContactPerson.Position property. It will say JavaScriptSerializer not to serialize that property and it will break circular reference.

Comment: It's good to know about this attribute (thus the +1) but I just found out that you must include System.Web.Script.Serialization to use this attribute.  The op's library (much like mine) is POCO (Plain Old C#/CLR Objects) and adding a reference to the above library will break that concept.

Comment: If you want to have strict architecture you will have to create separate data transfer objects in service layer and convert your POCO class to DTO marked with serialization attributes.